# FOP Pdf genaration with graphs(Pie/Bar) CHarts

Tags: java, xslt, charts, apache-fop

I am searching from nearly one month to generate graphs using Apache-FOP Pdf Generation. Finally I am asking you coders.Please help me.

```
<metrics>
    <duration>22s.531ms</duration>
    <failed>1</failed>
    <passed>2</passed>
    <skipped>6</skipped>
    <total>9</total>
</metrics>
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Some xslt I suppose? Some xml as well? And charts as png... ?

Comment: @Jan Thank you for your reply. I don't know how to write xslt for that one. XML I ll edit the question & add it

Comment: Then maybe you dont want to start fop at all and chose an easier way like itext to make your pdf.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I am not allowed to use itextpdf.

Comment: Not allowed because this is an assignment or because of legal issues? There might still be an (old) LGPL version of itext around

Comment: Using FOP I have generated tables & all. But the end of the table using above xml i have to generate graph.

Comment: Ah. Okay. I suggest creating the chart elsewhere, store it as image and put that image in pdf with fop

Comment: no no. we have some licensing issue with the itextpdf. even though it is free

Comment: could you please give an example of creating image graphs in java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98422/discussion-between-jan-and-manikanta-reddy).

Answer (score 1):

Once you managed to create a nice chart using any chart library you like ( like JFreeChart or similar), check out these examples from the [Apache FOP website](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/examples.html) on how to embed the generated image into your pdf:

```
<fo:block>
The image (
  <fo:external-graphic content-width="100pt" content-height="50pt" scaling="non-uniform" src="images/fop.jpg"/>
) has non-uniform scaling.
</fo:block>

<fo:block>
The image (
<fo:external-graphic content-width="50pt" content-height="100pt" scaling="non-uniform" src="images/fop.jpg"/>
) has non-uniform scaling.
</fo:block>

<fo:block>
The image (
<fo:external-graphic content-width="100pt" content-height="75pt" scaling="uniform" src="images/fop.jpg"/>
) has uniform scaling.
</fo:block>

<fo:block>
The image (
<fo:external-graphic content-width="75pt" content-height="100pt" scaling="uniform" src="images/fop.jpg"/>
) has uniform scaling.
</fo:block>

<fo:block>
The image (
<fo:external-graphic width="75pt" height="100pt" content-width="scale-to-fit" content-height="scale-to-fit" src="images/fop.jpg"/>
) is scaled to fit the viewport.
</fo:block>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jan I ll try to use this & let u know.